# How to speed up performance of autocomplete from indexeddb database

Tags: javascript, async-await, jquery-ui-autocomplete, indexeddb

I have jQuery autocomplete field that has to search through several thousand items, populated from an IndexedDB query (using the `idb` wrapper). The following is the autocomplete function called when the user begins typing in the box. `hasKW()` is a function that finds keywords.

```
async function siteAutoComplete(request, response) {
  const db = await openDB('AgencySite');
  const hasKW = createKeyWordFunction(request.term);

  const state = "NY";
  const PR = 0;
  const agency_id = 17;
  const range = IDBKeyRange.bound([state, PR, agency_id], [state, PR, agency_id || 9999999]);
  let cursor = await db.transaction('sites').store.index("statePRAgency").openCursor(range);
  let result = [];

  while (cursor) {
    if (hasKW(cursor.value.name)) result.push({
      value: cursor.value.id,
      label: cursor.value.name
    });
    cursor = await cursor.continue();
  }

  response(result);

}
```

My question is this: I'm not sure if the cursor is making everything slow. Is there a way to get all database rows that match the query without using a cursor? Is building the `result` array slowing me down? Is there a better way of doing this? Currently it takes 2-3s to show the autocomplete list.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be useful to someone else. I removed the cursor and just downloaded the whole DB into a javascript array and then used `.filter`. The speedup was dramatic. It took 2300ms using the way above and about 21ms using this:

```
  let result = await db.transaction('sites').store.index("statePRAgency").getAll();
  response(result.filter(hasKW));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an index, where by the term *index*, I mean a custom built one that represents a search engine index. You cannot easily and efficiently perform "startsWith" style queries over one of indexedDB's indices because they are effectively whole value (or least lexicographic).

There are many ways to create the search engine index I am suggesting. You probably want something like a prefix-tree, also known informally as a *trie*.

Here is a nice article by John Resig that you might find helpful: https://johnresig.com/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/. Otherwise, I suggest searching around on Google for trie implementations and then figuring out how to represent a similar data structure within an indexedDb object store or indexdDb index on an object store.

Essentially, insert the data first without the properties used by the index. Then, in an "indexing step", visit each object and index its value, and set the properties used by the indexedDb index. Or do this at time of insert/update.

From there, you probably want to open a connection shortly after page load and keep it open for the entire duration of the page. Then query against the index every time a character is typed (probably want to rate limit this call to refrain from querying more than n/second, perhaps using some kind of debounce helper function).

On the other hand, I might be a bit rusty on this one, but maybe you can create an index on the string prop, then use a lower bound that is the entered characters. A string that is lesser length than another string that contains it is present earlier in lexicographic order. So maybe it is actually that easy. You would also need to impose an upper bound that contains the entered characters thus far concatenated with some kind of sentinel value that can never realistically exist in the data, something silly like ZZZZZ.

Try this out in the browser's console:

```js
indexedDB.cmp('test', 'tasting'); // 1
indexedDB.cmp('test', 'testing'); // -1
indexedDB.cmp('test', 'test'); // 0
```

You essentially want to experiment with a query like this:

```
const sentinel = 'ZZZ';
const index = store.index('myStore');
const bounds = IDBKeyRange.bound(value, value + sentinel);
const request = index.get(bounds);
```

You might need to tweak the sentinel, experiment with other parameters to IDBKeyRange.bound (the inclusive/exclusive flags), probably need to store the value in homogenized case so that the search is case insensitive, avoid every sending a query when nothing has been typed, etc.